# Nginx rejects urls like example.com/index.php/some/virtual/path

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I just installed NGINX with default configuration and modified config only to accept PHP. PHP is working fine, but my NGINX is not recognizing urls like below:

> example.com/index.php/some/virtual/path

How do I get NGINX to recognize such path? I am guessing it isn't recognizing the .htaccess file.

My HTACCESS file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/HQutZ9JL

My current Nginx configuration is: http://pastebin.com/AfFyS8J4

Answer (score 0):

nginx does not support Apache *.htaccess* files.  You will need to rewrite your ruleset in the nginx configuration file.  From a quick look at your configuration file, I would start over and [enable PHP using FastCGI](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI) instead of trying to recreate your specific configuration.